# PHP if-else statement throws syntax error unexpected if

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel

I have a rather complicated if-else statement and I need help.

I just want to check if there is a value in the Session and if yes, ouput a string called "alert-important", that is going to function as a hook for changes in the future.

The part that does not work is the second part with the if-statement.

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') . ' worksfine ' . if(Session::has('flash_notification.important') ? 'alert-important' : '') }} ">
```

I get the error

```
"syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be ternary so it should be

`(Session::has('flash_notification.important') ? 'alert-important' : '')`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this statement is the offender

`if(Session::has('flash_notification.important')`

Shorthand `if/else statements` don't use the `if` keyword. This is the correct way:

`(Session::has('flash_notification.important')`